# retrieve computer name on domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

Good morning. I currently have a domain controller (Windows server 2019) where there are approximately 500 users and computers.

when a computer x is damaged, it reinstalls the operating system. The question is, how can I return to the same name that the computer had?

Is there any way to assign the automatic name to the computer, according to my organizational unit?.

Comment: That would depend on how the operating system is installed/endpoints are provisioned.

Comment: This question is lacking some context to provide any meaningful answer. Like what mechanism is reinstalling the operating system? And how is it joining the domain?